# How to ascertain input values to various functions in streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

This question my be a very primitive question with Java 8 collections.

How can I understand better how Java 8 passes input values between various stages within stream processing. If there is documentation explaining this clearly I am happy to read through, but I couldn't come across any.

For example, the groupingBy takes in a Function called classifier, this take in T type and transforms to K type.

```
static <T,K> Collector<T,?,Map<K,List<T>>> 
    groupingBy(Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier)
```

In the below example, we are passing on only type K. It is not clear when in streams the input values (Type T) will be automatically considered? How can I understand this better?

```
Map<BlogPostType, List<BlogPost>> postsPerType = posts.stream()
.collect(groupingBy(BlogPost::getType));
```

Comment: I've given [answering this a try](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52390754/1746118), not very sure if I was able to do the justice to the question though. Maybe, you can go through and let me know if that helps you understand things better.

Answer (score 1):

> In the below example, we are passing on only type K. It is not clear
>   when in streams the input values (Type T) will be automatically
>   considered?

```
Map<BlogPostType, List<BlogPost>> postsPerType = posts.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(BlogPost::getType));
```

Notice the method reference in the code, which is an equivalent to the functional interface [`Function<T,R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)
with the only method `apply` represented as `getType()` method from `BlogPost` in your code.

> How can I understand this better?

One of the ways to understand the code better is to just rewrite the simplified code:

```
Function<? super BlogPost, ? extends BlogPostType> classifier = BlogPost::getType;
// ^^^__you can see the correlation with Collectors#groupingBy(classifier)

Map<BlogPostType, List<BlogPost>> postsPerType = posts.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier));
```

with a return type from the *groupingBy* being **`Collector<BlogPost, ?, Map<BlogPostType, List<BlogPOst>>>`**  you can further collect the *postPerType* thanks to the Stream's *collect* implementaion which has the signature [`<R, A>` **`R`** `collect(Collector<? super T, A,`**`R`**`> collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-).